# when i try adding an object to the collection, all the object values are changed to the current object, how?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook, I want to read the column values from 'input1' sheet, and based on the column value copy the row from 'input' sheet, and store it in a class object. Do it for all the column entries in 'input1' sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call PrepareOutput
End Sub
Public Sub PrepareOutput()
   Dim i, indexValue,inputIndexRow As Integer
   Dim bills As New Collection
   inputIndexRow = 2
   indexValue= Worksheets("Input1").Cells(inputIndexRow , 1).Value

   While (Not IsEmpty(indexValue))
      i = indexValue+ 1
      Dim bill As New bill
      bill.quantity = Worksheets("Input1").Cells(inputIndexRow , 2).Value
      bill.cost = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 3).Value
      bills.Add bill
      inputIndexRow = inputIndexRow + 1
      indexValue= Worksheets("Input1").Cells(inputIndexRow , 1).Value
   Wend
End Sub

'class Bill has these public variables
Public service As String
Public serialNumber As Byte
Public cost As Double
Public quantity As Byte
```

[image: After adding first object]

[image: after adding second object]

Comment: You should indent your code properly so that it is easier to read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to create new instance of bill in your loop. Your definition `Dim bill As New bill` declares the variable `bill` and creates an instance, but although this is within your loop, it is not creating a new instance for every iteration.

So change your code to

```
While (Not IsEmpty(indexValue))
    Dim bill As bill
    set bill = new bill
    bill.quantity = Worksheets("Input1").Cells(inputIndexRow , 2).Value
    ...
Wend
```